# regex in url and xpath

Tags: php, regex, xpath

I have used xpath to crawl all href value in a `ul` `li` `a`.

```
foreach ($domExemple as $exemple) {

  $result[$i++] = $exemple->nodeValue;

}
```

Where `$exemple->nodeValue` is a string like /produit/3017620424403/nutella
I want to retrieve all number between the two /
They have different length...

I tried this **regex** : `/\/([0-9]{0,})/i`

But it returns not the good thing...

Anyone to explain me and help me ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I would suggest using an online regex tool where you can configure which programming language you would like to test regex for. The first one I found on google is [this one](https://regex101.com/). That way you can experiment easily. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your pattern you have to add the forward slash at the end as well:

```
/\/([0-9]{0,})\//i
              ^^
```

You don't have to escape the forward slash if you change to another delimiter like for example `~` and `{0,}` can be written as `*` but would also match an empty string. You might update it to use a `+` instead to match 1+ times a digit.

```
$pattern = "~/([0-9]+)/~i";
```

Your value is in the first capturing group. Note that there is no start boundary so if there are multiple parts in the string with /digits/ then those will also be matched.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CDAiUC/1)

Another option could be to match both forward slashes from the start of the string and make use of `\K` to forget what was matched. Then match 1+ digits and assert what is on the right is a `/`

```
^/[^/]+/\K\d+(?=/)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fUbaBK/1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the URL is in the format provided above, try this:

```
@(/[0-9]*/)@
```

`@` are chosen as delimiters so we won't have to escape the slashes and have messy code.

If you want just the numbers, use this:

```
@/([0-9]*)/@
```

The paranthesis will group what you are looking for.

Comment: A PCRE cheat sheet can be found here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#105924